# Баг Outlook 2016

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, email, outlook

регулярно сталкиваюсь с проблемой при верстке писем, в outlook2016 случайным образом начинают появляться горизонтальные полосы, вроде бордеров. В других клиентах такой проблемы не наблюдается, только outlоok2016 под Windows (на mac все нормально).
[image: случайная горизонтальная полоса]
В самой верстке нет ничего, кто мог бы дать этот бордер или фон.
Что это может быть и как с этим бороться?

Comment: Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой, и помогли игры с размером шрифта,правда у меня была такая штука что разрыв между блоками убирался изменением шрифта в совершенно другом блоке, и фиксился на аутлуке на 7 винде,а на 10-ке разрыв был в другом месте и тоже убрался изменением размера шрифта в другом блоке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что это может быть?

Известный баг аутлука 2016. В нем сменили движок рендеринга, на более бажный (насколько мне известно бага распространяется на все майкрософтовские продукты с этим движком). Коллеги которые верстают письма при упоминании этого бага очень матерятся и покрываются пятнами.
Точный механизм возникновения неизвестен.

Официального патча нет, когда будет и будет ли - неизвестно. Баг в статусе "ваше сообщение очень важно для нас, мы работаем над этим". ([Источник](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1f4f1e03-8ad5-4079-bc18-8fcaaa7b785d/outlook-2016-renders-horizontal-lines-seemingly-randomly-in-html-emails?forum=Office2016ITPro))

Как бороться?
Черт знает. Плясать с бубном.
Например **менять размеры шрифтов** на плюс-минус пиксель чаще всего помогает, баг проявляется при определенных размерах шрифтов, при этом если эта закономерность есть она неочевидна.

Как пляшут с бубном другие люди можно посмотреть здесь:
https://mosaico.io/email-client-tricks/outlook-2016-weird-1px-horizontal-lines/     и здесь:
https://litmus.com/community/discussions/4990-outlook-2016-1px-horizontal-lines-showing-up-in-the-body

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,
есть предположение, что это из за таблиц, в большом письме ими приходилось делать отступы для точности, но потом этих "полос" появилось ОЧЕНЬ много и пришлось отказаться в пользу BR, и по мере уменьшения таблиц, уменьшалось и количество полос. пришлось пожертвовать перфектпикселем, но лучше так, чем с полосами.

Comment: @Neka, из за таблиц-то скорее всего да, а вот что конкретно делает таблицу плохой - не вполне ясно. По ссылкам которые я привел полтора десятка хаков и предположений перечислено